# How to get selected item in Bootstrap 3 dynamic dropdown modal dialog from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 to show a modal dialog with at dropdown selection. The dropdown allows the user to select a page in a pdf. It is dynamically populated just prior to showing the dialog. The dialog works well and the dropdown is correctly populated with page items.

[image]

The non-working code is here.

```js
function choosePage(numPages) {
  var pdfPageSelector = document.getElementById("pdfPageSelector");
  for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = "#";
    anchor.id = "page_id";
    var text = document.createTextNode("page " + i);
    text.href = "#";
    anchor.appendChild(text);
    opt.appendChild(anchor);

    anchor.onclick = function() {
      alert('clicked');
    };
    pdfPageSelector.appendChild(opt);
  }
  
  $('#page_id').on('click', function(e){
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor functionality
  });

  $('#page_id').click(function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor functionality
  });

}

choosePage(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="pdfChooseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Choose page to redact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
          Please choose page to redact.
        </div>

        <select class="form-control" id="pdfPageSelector">
        </select>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="pageChosen()">Choose</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Bootstrap 3 changes the way that dropdown selections are implemented. I cannot figure out how read the index or value of the selected item. A fallback is to implement an event that is fired when the element is selected (the old Bootstrap 2 method doesn't work seem anymore).

I have tried adding onclick event handler in pure javascript:

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.id = "page_id";
anchor.onclick = function() {
  alert('clicked');
};
```

I have tried adding .click and .on in jQuery:

```
$('#page_id').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor functionality.
  alert('clicked');
});
```

or .click

```
$('#page_id').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor functionality.
  alert('clicked');
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must understand that when you are using `select` tag of html, **you will not get any click event** either of `select` tag or its `option` tag. **you will only have `onchange` event** of `select` tag. i have done as follow when you select any option from dropdown, alert will come and i have bind onchange event as follow:

```
 $('#pdfPageSelector').on('change',function(e){
    alert('fired');
  });
```

```js
function choosePage(numPages) {
  var pdfPageSelector = document.getElementById("pdfPageSelector");
  for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = "#";
    anchor.id = "page_id";
    var text = document.createTextNode("page " + i);
    text.href = "#";
    anchor.appendChild(text);
    opt.appendChild(anchor);

    anchor.onclick = function() {
      alert('clicked');
    };
    pdfPageSelector.appendChild(opt);
  }
  
  $('#pdfPageSelector').on('change',function(e){
    alert('fired');
  });
  
  $('#page_id').on('click', function(e){
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor functionality
  });

  $('#page_id').click(function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor functionality
  });

}

choosePage(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="pdfChooseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Choose page to redact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
          Please choose page to redact.
        </div>

        <select class="form-control" id="pdfPageSelector">
        </select>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="pageChosen()">Choose</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Ah! select and option are basic html. Should have known this!

Comment: actually you will get click cross browser but will register to open as well as when you make choice. `<option>` will register in some browsers but definitely not IE. I'm not saying you are wrong. Using `clcik` on select is useless

Answer (score 0):

To expand on innodel's answer (and clean up the code example)

The select and option elements are standard html elements:

To get a callback anytime the user changes the selection, add an .onchange event handler:

```
<select class="form-control" id="pdfPageSelector" onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

To get the value of the selection from javascript, use:

```
var dropdownSelector = document.getElementById("pdfPageSelector");
console.log(dropdownSelector.value);
```

The updated working code is:

```js
function choosePage(numPages) {
  var pdfPageSelector = document.getElementById("pdfPageSelector");
  for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = "#";
    anchor.id = "page_id";
    var text = document.createTextNode("page " + i);
    text.href = "#";
    anchor.appendChild(text);
    opt.appendChild(anchor);

    // Basic html method:
    pdfPageSelector.onchange = function() {
      var pdfPageSelector = document.getElementById("pdfPageSelector");
      var selectionValue = pdfPageSelector.value;
      alert('Basic onchange fired with value: ' + selectionValue );
    };
    pdfPageSelector.appendChild(opt);
  }
  
  // jQuery method:
  $('#pdfPageSelector').on('change',function(e){
      var selectionValue = this.value;
      alert('jQuery onchange fired with value: ' + selectionValue );
  });
}

// Called when button is pressed.
function pageChosen() {
  var pdfPageSelector = document.getElementById("pdfPageSelector");
  var selectionValue = pdfPageSelector.value;
  alert('Chosen item: ' + selectionValue );
}

choosePage(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="pdfChooseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Choose page to redact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
          Please choose page to redact.
        </div>

        <select class="form-control" id="pdfPageSelector"  onchange="alert(this.value)">
        </select>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="pageChosen()">Choose</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```